Is there something wrong with the LaggedStart class in manim?
I am new to manim and am employing the use of updater functions to change the size of a specific animation. (It is from the first Brian Amedee tutorial) It works when I separate the objects to be animated but when I use the LaggedStart class, it doesn't enlarge at all.
This is the code I have:
from manim import *

class CircleGettingBigger(Scene):
    def construct(self):

        r = ValueTracker(0.5)

        circle = always_redraw(lambda : 
                        Circle(radius = r.get_value(), stroke_color = YELLOW,
                        stroke_width = 5)
                )
        
        line_radius = always_redraw(lambda:
                      Line(start = circle.get_center(), end = circle.get_bottom(), stroke_color = RED_B, stroke_width = 10)
        )

        triangle = always_redraw(lambda :
                    Polygon(circle.get_top(), circle.get_left(), circle.get_right(), stroke_color = GREEN_C)
        )
        self.play(LaggedStart(
            Create(circle), 
            DrawBorderThenFill(line_radius), 
            DrawBorderThenFill(triangle),
            run_time = 4, 
            lag_ratio = 0.05
        ))

        self.play(r.animate.set_value(2), run_time = 5)

Here is the video link:
https://imgur.com/a/HU8Q71j
If you are unable to see the video at this time, the video plays the three objects but does not enlarge them.
However, if I do not use LaggedStart as in this code:
class CircleGettingBigger(Scene):
    def construct(self):

        r = ValueTracker(0.5)

        circle = always_redraw(lambda : 
                        Circle(radius = r.get_value(), stroke_color = YELLOW,
                        stroke_width = 5)
                )
        
        line_radius = always_redraw(lambda:
                      Line(start = circle.get_center(), end = circle.get_bottom(), stroke_color = RED_B, stroke_width = 10)
        )

        triangle = always_redraw(lambda :
                    Polygon(circle.get_top(), circle.get_left(), circle.get_right(), stroke_color = GREEN_C)
        )
        self.play(Create(circle), run_time = 1)
        self.play(DrawBorderThenFill(line_radius), run_time = 1)
        self.play(DrawBorderThenFill(triangle), run_time = 1)

        self.play(r.animate.set_value(2), run_time = 5)

Using the code above, it enlarges as planned.
https://imgur.com/a/RNjJbuD
What can I do to fix that?

yes, it looks like a bug.  you can create an issue on the github page.

@James Sorry, I am so inexperienced; where and what is the github page?

Github is a code hosting service where open source projects such as manim store their code and allow users to propose changes, create bug reports, and track changes.  The URL for this project's issue page is: https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/issues .  You can create an account and then click the "New Issue" button.  It will guide you from there, including a bug report template.
